Putting a column index under every column
I'm picking a library for reporting, all reports have the strange design I've never seen before. Maybe, it's search issue, but I found no clues how to do this at all.
Here is typical report layout:
| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 |
__________________________________
|    1     |    2     |    3     |
__________________________________
| Data 1   | Data 2   |   Data 3 |

So, under every column there is centered column index. Even worse, if report is dynamic, it is not enough to hide a column, but also fix index, leaving most template based libraries out of question. Index always has it's own style (align and font size), so this row can't be added in DataSource.
Any ideas how can I do this in Dynamic Reports?
